# Javascript: How to delay or retrigger an event without an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two textbox: `INNnumber` and `Nyilv`. `INNnumber` is an autocomplete field (based on Sharepoint Service) so if the user start to type a number, the possible options are appears in a dropdown menu and the user can select the right number for him/her. The `Nyilv` field is a scriptcalculated field based on the `INNnumber` (INNnumber's value+".A."+"BBB"). The `Nyilv` field is calculated when the `INNnumber` field lose focus, but I have a little problem.

If the user start to type, for example enters the number "6" and all numbers appear in the dropdown menu starting with number "6" so the user stop typing and select for example "611" then the result in the `Nyilv` field will be "6.A.BBB" insted of "611.A.BBB". So looks like the field lose focus when the user click on the dropdown menu what is too early. Here is the code of the autofill by textbox change:

> **JavaScript Code :**

```
$(function() {
  $("input[id='INNnumber_ffb3c6db-3d8d-4aa4-bb93-89a8353a2fea_$NumberField']").blur(function() {
    $("input[id='Nyilv_x00e1_ntart_x00e1_si_x0020_0b9d314c-2f8a-4ab9-9046-95af91dc0123_$TextField']").val(document.getElementById("INNnumber_ffb3c6db-3d8d-4aa4-bb93-89a8353a2fea_$NumberField").value+'.A.'+'BBB');
  });
});
```

**So what I need in time is:**

1. The user click on the number.
2. The `INNnumber` lose focus the `Nyilv` is refreshed. (Too early)
3. The `INNnumber` is getting the numbers the user selected. (Too late)
4. **I need to trigger somehow an event to focus and lose focus on the `INNnumber` field to activate the .blur event again without creating an infinite loop.**

I am not sure my 4th idea is the best way to solve the problem...

Comment: `.change(...)` instead of `.blur(...)`
and `this` in the event handler is the element which triggered the event, hence `document.getElementById("INNnumber_ffb3c6db-3d8d-4aa4-bb93-89a8353a2fea_$NumberField").value === this.value`

Comment: Okey I changed the .blur to .change, but I am not sure I understand correctly the 2. "this" part of your idea. (I am new to javascript syntax) May I ask you to insert here the complete code with your changes? Thank you very much!

Comment: Inside the event handler you can access the element which triggered the event via `this`. So in your example `document.getElementById("INNnumber_ffb3c6db-3d8d-4aa4-bb93-8‌​9a8353a2fea_$NumberF‌​ield").value` would be the same as `this.value`: `.blur(function() { $("#Nyilv_x00e1_ntart_x00e1_si_x0020_0b9d314c-2f8a-4ab9-9046-95af91dc0123_$TextField").val(this.value + ".A.BBB"); })`

Comment: I see I got it now. Thank you very much! But looks like if I fill the textbox from the dropdown menu it is not count as a change so the result is the same. In the end I created an other "onclick" event for the dropdown list and now works correctly, but this way I also have to check if the user enter the full data manualy without clicking on the list ect. It would be better If change/blur works correcly.